# Cancellativity of a particular $2$-generated monoid presented by an infinite number of relations

Tags: reference-request, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $X = \{x, y\}$ be a two-element set, and let $H$ be the monoid defined by the presentation
$$
\langle x, y \mid x y^k x = y x y^{k+1} x y, \text{ for } k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots\rangle.
$$
That is, $H$ is the quotient of the free monoid over $X$ by the smallest (monoid) congruence $\mathscr C$ such that $x y^k x \equiv y x y^{k+1} x y\bmod \mathscr C$ for every $k \in \mathbf N$.

To illustrate a certain phenomenon in factorization theory, I need to show that $H$ is cancellative (i.e., if $uv = uw$ or $vu = wu$ for some $u, v, w \in H$, then $v = w$). [Qinghai Zhong](https://imsc.uni-graz.at/zhong/) has a proof that the conclusion is correct. But his proof is relatively long, and the paper where I need the result is already longish. So I'm hoping for a positive answer to the following question:

> **Q.** Is there any ``criterion for cancellativity" in the literature that can be used to show in a more or less straightforward way that the monoid $H$ is cancellative?

One approach to prove that a monoid is cancellative is to show that it embeds into a group. A survey of conditions for group-embeddability is provided by Alan James Cain in Sect. 0.9.1 of [his Ph.D. thesis](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~alanc/pub/c_phdthesis.html). Unfortunately, I couldn't make any of the criteria surveyed in Cain's thesis work in my case. On the other hand, it is perhaps worth recalling that, by work of A.I. Mal'cev, a cancellative monoid need not be embeddable into a group, so thinking in terms of group-embeddability might be misleading.

Comment: The thing I would try is to prove that $yxy^{k+1}xy\to xy^kx$ is a complete rewriting system.  It is clearly terminating since it is length reducing. To check confluence you need only check local confluence (i.e.that all overlaps can be resolved).  I am very busy this week so I have not time to check this, but it seems plausible since overlaps of the relations seem very small.  Then one can try to use the complete rewriting system to check that left and right multiplication by a generator are injective,  Good  luck.

Comment: It is not confluent, but can be completed.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Is this related to Theorem 3.9 in F. Chouraqui's *Rewriting Systems and Embedding of Monoids in Groups* (http://www.heldermann-verlag.de/gcc/gcc01/gcc010_b.pdf)? I wasn't aware of this approach to group-embeddability of monoids, and I'd appreciate some references for studying.

Comment: Not really.  She assumes a complete rewriting system for the group you would like to embed in of a special form. I was indicating that complete rewriting systems are good for directly checking cancellation using the normal forms.   In general cancellation is much easier to check than group embeddability.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Got it, thanks! Would you recommend any paper or book where I can read about complete rewriting systems and how to use them for proving cancellativity?

Comment: Mark Sapir's book on combinatorial algebra talks about rewriting systems.  There is also a book by Book and Otto on string rewriting systems whose name I forget.  I don't think any book will talk specifically about cancellation.  Rewriting systems give normal forms.  You have to show left multiplying a normal form by two different generators gives different normal forms.